# When using SIP/{Number}@{Provider} format for call , transport=udp parameter is missing in request URI of SIP INVITE

Tags: asterisk, sip, invite

Transport parameter is not sent in Request URI when used SIP/{Number}@{Provider}  format for calling in dial plan, but when use SIP/{Provider}, transport parameter is sent in the request URI.

I want to send transport parameter even in SIP/{Number}@{Provider} format.

Answer (score 0):

That just mean you have both tcp and udp and first is tcp.

Comment: But there is no transport parameter is sent in invite  request Uri line...